# Stop and resume Javascript execution when condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, I'm writing this question because the other answers over there didn't help me.

I have a page that has a setTimeOut function running, and when the user clicks a certain div, an input is presented, so I need the setTimeOut stop until he enter some text and press ok, then the setTimeOut can continue when It was.

Please any help will be very useful :)

Comment: So you begin a timeout with: `var to = setTimeout(...);`. You can stop it with `clearTimeout(to);`. You can restart it by calling the `setTimeout(...)` again. However, that's an extreme simplification and I think you're going to need more control than that. Could you provide some context, such as a [mcve]. Without further details this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Can you post the answer please because I need the setTimeout to pause and then resume when it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout`

The [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) returns an id which can be used to cancle the timeout out operation later.

As a copy directly from MDN, it should look like this;

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello") }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

If you need to **pause** the timeout rather than stopping it you will need to do you own math as to how much time is remaining and then start a new timeout with a new `setTimeout` after you cleared the first one

Comment: So how would be the function that stops the setTimeout and the function that resumes it? That would answer the question

Comment: There is no _resume_ -- I updated the answer to indicate how you will have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout simply schedules the operation to happen at a certain time in future.

If you only need to cancel the next thing happening at timeout then you can use handle returned by the function window.setTimeout to call window.clearInterval and then schedule it again at some point of future.

If you for some reason don't want to use the previous approach for example because you don't want to reschedule the intervals, then you can create a flag in the closure to indicate whether the function should be run.

```
var shouldHappen = true;
window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(shouldHappen){
        // Do some stuff. 
    }
}, 1000)
```